# showing 'loading content message'

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, web-frontend

I'm using this to load events dynamically without a page refresh, but there's a bit too much time on the load so for better UX I thought we should add 'loading events' or similar but my attempts have been in vain so far.

```
function calendarAjax () {

    $('#month_nav a').live('click', function() {
        $('#events_container').animate({ opacity: "0" }, 200 ).load($(this).attr('href')+' #events_content' , function(){
            $(this).animate({ opacity: "1" }, 600 );
        });
        return false;
    })

};
```

Any assistance very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways, here's a global loading image/text code using [$ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [$.ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/)

```
$('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Assuming your loading div's ID is `loadingDiv` which contains either text or loading image.

**Update**

[$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a jQuery [Shorthand method](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) which like several others e.g. [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [$getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) uses the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) function under the hood.

[$.ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) is a way to register a callback to be executed when the first ajax request starts and 
[$.ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) is used the same way to register a callback to be executed when all ajax request completes

So if you use the above code to show and hide a loading div, it will automatically show that loading text/image when your `$.load` function's ajax request starts and hide when the ajax request completes, assuming you have only one `$.ajax` or `$.ajax` shorthand method in that page.

Comment: Updated the answer which will give you an idea of how you can use that code with your current setup. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 things:

A loader:

```
<div id="loader">
I'm loading something
</div>
```

CSS for your loader:

```
#loader {
   /* some design */
}
```

THen you need to make a javascript method that will toggle its visibility:

```
var loader = {
    show: function() {
        $('#loader').show();
    },
    hide: function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    }
};
```

Then you can simply just say `loader.show()` whenever you want something to be *loading*, and `loader.hide()` when you want to dismiss that message.

Answer (score 0):

The [Jquery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) is perfect for your needs.